# Date Comparison Issue VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare Dates in a vba script. I believe the main issue is my formatting however I am not sure how to solve it.

```
Sub Rem9()
Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 wsName = ws.Name

 lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  FirstDateRead = CDate("1, 1,2018") 'Initialize the first Day of the year as the last day

For i = 1 To lr
Debug.Print FirstDateRead
Debug.Print ws.Cells(i, 1).Value

 If FirstDateRead > ws.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
               ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = 121325

End If

Next i
End Sub
```

According to my output the First Date Read is never greater than the values I am pulling, Which it is for all cases. I have included here an example of the debug.print from the script I am running to show the date formats. Additionally I want to confirm the values I am drawing from are indeed datevaluse as when I run them through the IsDate() Function it returns True. [image]

One other issue if that my date format for the value I call is swapping the year and day. Does anyone know how to solve that. When I use the format function it returns the date as. [image]

Comment: none of your 4 example values is larger than *Jan 1st 2018* ?!

Comment: @FunThomas ya that is why I am having an issue with FirstDateRead should be greater than ws.Cells(i,1).Value.  Sorry for bad wording

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `DateDiff` function instead:

```
Sub dateDifference()

    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date

    d1 = CDate("1, 2,2018")
    d2 = Range("A1").Value ' insert a date in A1 to test

    Debug.Print DateDiff("d", d1, d2) ' first parameter set to days

End Sub
```

**Edit #1**

Use `Format` to compare apples with apples, so to speak:

```
d2 = Format(Range("A1").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: This function will definitely work however I am running into one more issue the cell value dates I am calling are registering the first value as the year and the last value as the day so 21-FEB-17 from the photo is registering as 2021-Feb-17. Do you have any idea how I could solve this part.

Comment: That is what I have been trying but it just outputs the the year and day swapped in the new format. I include the issue I am having in the main question with an edit.

Comment: Sure, that's what it's supposed to do, but the result should change when you apply it to the `DateDiff` function afterwards.

Comment: The DateDiff Function is working yes but it is giving a value of -1143 days because the datevalue I am outputting is being read reversed for day and year.

Comment: This is probably a document formatting issue then. When inserting the date values into the document, please make sure they're inserted in the proper format. Otherwise, you have to factor this into your code, which is considerably more arduous than the approach you're attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cells containing the dates are in text format, try wrapping the comparison value in a cDate:

```
If FirstDateRead > Cdate(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = 121325
End If
```